# Specify ML workloads to connect to Cloud Spanner Read Only replicas

Tags: google-cloud-spanner, looker

Is there a way in the JDBC connection string to specify ML workloads to connect to Spanner's Read-Only replicas? Spanner's infrastructure efficiently handles such Read-only transactions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the JDBC driver to connect directly to a read-only replica, but you can use read-only transactions and specify the read staleness of the transaction (or a single query). This will effectively allow Cloud Spanner to execute the query on the closest read-only replica. Use the [SET READ_ONLY_STALENESS](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/jdbc-session-mgmt-commands#set_read_only_staleness) command for this.

Example for a single query:

```sql
-- Set the max staleness to 15 seconds.
-- Cloud Spanner will choose the most efficient timestamp to
-- execute the query. This only works in auto commit mode.
SET READ_ONLY_STALENESS='MAX_STALENESS 15s';

SELECT * FROM my_table;
```

Example for a read-only transaction with multiple queries:

```sql
BEGIN;

-- Mark the transaction as read-only.
SET TRANSACTION READ ONLY;

-- MAX_STALENESS can only be used in auto commit.
-- Use EXACT_STALENESS or READ_TIMESTAMP for transactions.
SET READ_ONLY_STALENESS='EXACT_STALENESS 15s';

SELECT * FROM my_table;
SELECT * FROM other_table;

-- Read-only transactions are not really committed, but this
-- marks the end of the transaction for the JDBC driver.
COMMIT;
```